# Python Google Sheets Column Formating Issue

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have here a script that scrapes calendar data and imports it into google sheets. I'm having some issues though with formatting only column B in google sheets. There are 8 columns that print into my sheet but I'm trying to have it import the time data but also format the column to be set to time. I've tried the code below but it keeps changing the format of column B to automatic rather then Time.

```
  # Set the time format for the second column of the sheet
date_column = sheet.range('B:B')
for cell in date_column:
    cell.number_format = 'hh:mm AM/PM'
sheet.update_cells(date_column)
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I attached a picture of what it should look like in google sheet and here's the full script below:

```js
import random
import gspread
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
import time

# Define your Google Sheets credentials
creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('keys.json')
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = creds.with_scopes(scopes)

# Authenticate with Google Drive API
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Open the Google Sheets workbook
workbook = gc.open('forexfactorycalendar')
worksheet = workbook.worksheet('Sheet1')


# Specify the name of the sheet you want to write to
sheet_name = 'forexfactorycalendar'

# Open the specified sheet
sheet = gc.open(sheet_name).sheet1

def create_driver():
    user_agent_list = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.5; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
    ]
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)

    browser_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    browser_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    browser_options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    browser_options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080")
    browser_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
    browser_options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
    browser_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    browser_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=browser_options, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=test.log"])

    return driver

import time

def parse_data(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)

    data_table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "calendar__table")
    value_list = []

    for row in data_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr"):
        row_data = list(filter(None, [td.text for td in row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")]))
        if row_data:
            impact_element = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "calendar__impact")
            impact_class = impact_element.get_attribute("class")
            if "impact--low" in impact_class:
                impact = "low"
            elif "impact--medium" in impact_class:
                impact = "medium"
            elif "impact--high" in impact_class:
                impact = "high"
            else:
                impact = ""
            row_data.append(impact)
            value_list.append(row_data)
    return value_list

driver = create_driver()
url = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar'
value_list = parse_data(driver=driver, url=url)

# Clear existing data from sheet
sheet_range = sheet.range('A1:I' + str(len(value_list) + 1))
for cell in sheet_range:
    cell.value = ''
if sheet_range:
    sheet.update_cells(sheet_range)
    
# Set the time format for the first column of the sheet
date_column = sheet.range('B:B')
for cell in date_column:
    cell.number_format = 'hh:mm AM/PM'
sheet.update_cells(date_column)    

# Write the new data to the sheet
for value_index, value in enumerate(value_list):
    if '\n' in value[0]:
        date_str = value.pop(0).replace('\n', ' - ')
    row_index = value_index + 1

    
    # Write the impact value to column I
    worksheet.update_cell(row_index, 9, value[-1])
    
    # Write the remaining values to columns A-H
    worksheet.update(f'A{row_index}:I{row_index}', [[date_str] + value])
    
    # Add a delay of 1 second between requests
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear from your post - are the values displaying in Column B not the correct/expected values?  Or are the values correct while only the apparent Format setting of the column is not what you expect?

Comment: The values that import into the sheet are kind of wonky (there's an apostrophe at the beginning of the time) so google sheets thinks its text instead of time. Only when i change the format to Time on the column (B) in google sheets, it displays as time like in the picture example above. Since I'm using "# Clear existing data from sheet" i believe it's also changing the format to automatic so even if I set column B to TIME, when it imports, it changes it back to automatic. So i'm trying to get my script to set column B to Time format when importing data on that column.

Comment: It looks like you're currently opening the same spreadsheet twice.  First with `workbook = gc.open('forexfactorycalendar'); worksheet = workbook.worksheet('Sheet1')`.  Then a couple of lines later with `sheet_name = 'forexfactorycalendar'; sheet = gc.open(sheet_name).sheet1`.  You update the formats in `sheet`, but write the data to `worksheet`, which is probably overwriting your format changes

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! unfortunately it's still wont change the format of the column to Time...